# online tex to pdf converter that takes ref.bib files?

Tags: natbib, online

I need to convert a latex file to pdf as soon as possible, and found several useful resources online, such as cloudconvert

https://cloudconvert.com/tex-to-pdf.

The problem is, I can only upload a single tex file. Is there an online converter which will take both the tex source file and the ref.bib file to create a bibliography? If not, is there a straightforward way to paste the contents of the bib file into the tex file so that I have a single document? Note: the latex document that I'm working from uses the natbib package.

Comment: No, it is *not* possible (or better, it doesn’t make sense) to paste the contents of the `.bib` file into the `.tex` file.  What *is* possible is to paste the contents of the `.bbl` file into the `.tex` file.  But I’m afraid that won’t help you, since I guess that you don’t know how to generate a `.bbl` file from a `.bib` file either.

Comment: Have you tried Sharelatex? Make an account, upload your stuff and, assuming your code is fine, it works with several separate documents.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give Sharelatex a try, I think it will accomplish what I need.

Comment: Any updates here?